# C++ fstream: More signs readen than intended

Tags: c++, file

this issue is really strange to me.. I'm creating and writing into a simple file.
When I'm reading with this code:

```
return_chars = new char[10];

file.read(return_chars, 10);
```

The result simply contains 4 characters more! It's 14 signs long.
This happens only when reading 10 characters and some certain other numbers (24 for example).
At a length of 8 it doesn't happen.
The signs it adds are always the same at 10 characters: CE=0

This is the code I use for example to show what I read from the file:

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, return_chars, "title", 0);
```

Where is the issue? o.o
Lots of thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it's a bug with your showtext method?

Comment: `file.read()` doesn't null-terminate the string. If `showText()` expects a null terminator, it will be disappointed.

Comment: You're using C++, use std::string instead of C strings and you won't have problems like this.

Comment: sorry, the showText method is irrelevant. The second code part is how I am displaying the text! Can the issue be there?
And how do I use c++ strings with file.read? It doesn't accept a string..

Comment: it accepts a `char*`, and `&mystring[0]` is (unfortunately) the best way to get a `char*` out of a `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess from the limited information you gave, maybe the showText method doesn't handle the return_chars array correctly because it isn't a null terminated string? You could try,

```
return_chars = new char[11];

file.read(return_chars, 10);
return_chars[10] = '\0';

showText(return_chars);
```

Comment: Ahh, okey! Thank you, yes that was the issue! (will mark you answer as the right one in 6 minutes when I can, lol)